# BigQuery error when running query "Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 219019. Error: Missing close double quote (") character

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run simple SQL query `select * from table_name` in BigQuery and I am getting the following error:

> Error while reading table: *table_name*, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 219019. Error: Missing close double quote (") character.

I was able to run this query successfully last week, so I don't understand what would have changed. When I have looked it up, people are saying it is a newline character issue, but their experience with the error is when uploading data. This table I am querying comes from a BI connector, so there should be consistency each day in the process.

Why would I receive this error suddenly and how do I determine what changed to cause it?

Answer (score 0):

That error makes me suspicious that you're querying an external table (e.g. a bigquery table where the table content is backed by objects in cloud storage, etc).

If that's the case, any chance the files in cloud storage have been updated?  The error sounds like a malformed CSV or JSON file may be involved.

Comment: I don't have all of the information, as this was set up prior to my arrival, but I believe that the data is passing from the source system (an applicant tracking system) to Amazon, then to Google Cloud Platform and BigQuery. The table should be being refreshed on a daily basis. What types of things would cause this to break suddenly? Would something in the data itself possibly cause this, like the use of what should be a restricted character? I'm trying to figure out what triggered the error so that I know the resource I need to engage for the correction.

Comment: You may be able to examine the table details to understand where the files are hosted, but you'll likely need to engage with your team(s) responsible for the data pipeline for further assistance as they'll have more insight into the process.